# ipad 1 video mirroring full screen

Tags: ipad, video, mirroring

Im mirroring my app on a tv, using [this post about video mirroring for iPad](http://www.touchcentric.com/blog/), in an iPad1

the problem is that the image is not full screen,

how can i make the image full screen?

thanks!

Comment: The problem with mirroring an original iPad is that the resolution is so low that the image is scaled properly to avoid quality degradation, which is why you don't have a full screen image.

Comment: @esqew, thanks, but even at expense of quality, how can I make the image fill the whole screen?, thanks

Comment: I have an iPad 3, and I can't get it to mirror full screen either. The tv only support 4:3 and 16:9, however Video streaming from the iPad over airplay is full screen, just not when mirroring the ipad screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image most likely isn't scaled correctly because your iPad's aspect ratio is 4:3 whereas your TV (if HD) is most likely 16:9.

Comment: With the tv at 4:3 I get a vertical double-letterbox effect. It looks like, when mirroring, the iPad intentionally pushes a 16:9 black background with a 4:3 image in the middle.

When the tv is at 16:9 it's just a vertical single-letterbox effect, seemingly caused by the iPad.